# Good Local Bug Tracking Software?

Tags: local-files, bug-tracker

I know there are many bug tracking/project management programs out there. For my main project, I use Pivotal Tracker, and it is serving my needs just fine. But I have a side project that I want to also work on, but my full time won't be on that project. Because of that, I don't want to use Pivotal Tracker because it uses iterations and I don't want to be timed on my programming for this side project, since I really don't know when and how long I will be able to add to it.

So my question is this, are there any bug tracking programs that allow you to work on the local file system without having to run a whole web server or use a web browser or anything? In other words, are there any trackers that can save a small database somewhere on your local file system, and has a GUI front end to work with it.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I have looked around and I have come to the decision that TaskCoach is the best software for me. It is really good at helping you track tasks and it also helps in tracking how much time you are spending on them.

Answer (score 4):

For a side project, it doesn't sound like you need many fancy features. So what about a simple old-fashion spreadsheet?

Also relying on a standalone tool means you need to back-up your data. So, maybe you'd better go with something like google docs, what about [this template](https://docs.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AnURaNnJdkQsdGxkZXFzUEJZWUtpQzkwY1dDWkhaelE&mode=public)?

Comment: You're right that for a small project, a shared Excel spreadsheet could work just fine.  A spreadsheet is the most basic form of "database table", after all.